# How to turn on player level scroll over popup?

Tags: runescape

In Runescape how do you activate the player character scroll over level popup?

When you scroll over players by default a stat is shown. How do I disable/enable it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? When you roll your mouse over a player, nothing pops up for me...?

Answer (score 2):

For EoC interface mode: right-click the minimize button on the action bar and click "unsheath". Your character's weapons will be shown unsheathed, and players' combat levels will be displayed instead of their total skill level.

For Legacy interface mode: open combat settings, and click on the crossed swords icon in the top left corner to toggle weapons being sheathed/unsheathed.